# Resoving scheduled Akka actors in Play 2.1.1 just gives me RepointableActorRef

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I have a recurring Akka job that reads quotes from an external url that I start in my Global.scala. Like this:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    val collector = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[QuoteCollector], "quoteCollector")
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 10.seconds, collector, "tick")
  }
}
```

Now I want to access the data of the actor when somebody views the / page so I do this in the controller:

```
def index = Action {
  val actor:ActorRef = Akka.system.actorFor("akka://application/user/quoteCollector")
  val collector = actor.asInstanceOf[QuoteCollector]
  val list: List = collector.quotes
  Ok(views.html.index("hi"))
}
```

This is what happens every time:

```
error] application - 

! @6e1hjmdbo - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ClassCastException: akka.actor.RepointableActorRef cannot be cast to actors.QuoteCollector]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:326) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.lang.ClassCastException: akka.actor.RepointableActorRef cannot be cast to actors.QuoteCollector
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1.apply(Application.scala:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$index$1.apply(Application.scala:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Action.scala:254) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Action.scala:254) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:217) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
```

Any pointers on what just happened there and how I am supposed to fix it would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka shields you from actors. You are always dealing with addresses (`ActorRef`s) instead. So the actor **behind** the `ActorRef` should have logic to accept a message (like `case object GetQuotes`) and logic to send back your list of quotes (`List[Quote]`) as well.

Also check out [this part](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/futures.html) of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, of course I missed this crucial point when scanning the docs the first time.